# Formatting in the write statement in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I try to use write statement in Fortran. But the required format is not generated. 
When I change the format

```
 write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,E15.7)')
```

to

```
 write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,I7)')
```

it will give me there value as  *******

```
     0.2375528E-01  0.3807880E-02        *******
     0.1294881E-01  0.7272966E-01        *******
     0.9220393E-02 -0.7748791E-01        *******
     0.3838744E-02 -0.1024217E+00        *******
     0.4709786E-02 -0.2939432E-01        *******
```

Main Code:

```
 post = post+1
 write(filename,'(a,i5.5,a)') 'particles', post, '.dat'
 open ( unit=28, file=filename , recl=300 )
 write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,E15.7)') (xp(i,:), i=1,npart)
 close ( unit=28 )
```

Result form the code

```
     0.2375528E-01  0.3807880E-02        0.1E+01
     0.1294881E-01  0.7272966E-01        0.2E+01
     0.9220393E-02 -0.7748791E-01        0.3E+01
     0.3838744E-02 -0.1024217E+00        0.4E+01
     0.4709786E-02 -0.2939432E-01        0.5E+01
```

Required result needed in this format

```
     0.2375528E-01  0.3807880E-02        1
     0.1294881E-01  0.7272966E-01        2
     0.9220393E-02 -0.7748791E-01        3
     0.3838744E-02 -0.1024217E+00        4
     0.4709786E-02 -0.2939432E-01        5
```

Can anybody suggest me how I can get the required result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the numbers to integers

```
write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,I7)')  (xp(i,1:2),nint(xp(i,3)), i=1,npart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Request zero decimals

```
write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,F15.0)') (xp(i,:), i=1,npart)
```

Comment: `Fortran runtime error: Precision not greater than zero in format specifier 'E' or 'D'`

Comment: `write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,E15)') (xp(i,:), i=1,npart)` then. Don't make me load up the Fortran compiler to figure this out. The `I` specifier is for integer types only. Maybe `write(unit=28, fmt='(1X,E15.7,E15.7,G)') (xp(i,:), i=1,npart)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I would actually recommend, to try the code first, I did just that before posting my answer.

Comment: you can use `F15.0` if you don't mind a decimal point. `G` by itself (if your compiler supports it) leaves a bunch of trailing zeros